# What Module is used for the button's looks?

Tags: angular

Which module does the looks of the button (red mark selection )belong to in order to get the good looks?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import `MatButtonModule` see [API reference for Angular Material button](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api)

Then in your template:

```
<button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```